# Lots of microphone interferance on Freya

Tags: release-freya, sound

Microphone has a lot of interference which it doesn't have on the windows boot. This happens on a few different sound input applications, so it's not the fault of a single program either. The microphone is a 3.5mm jack type.

Clarification: This is a desktop PC.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a laptop? Does it happen when running on battery?

Comment: @SuiciDoga This is a desktop, not a laptop.

Comment: Does the AC plug have a ground pin

Comment: Yes, it does have a ground pin.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still searching for a solution,

I had the same problem of noise from my cheap microphone with Loki. I found the module "module-echo-cancel" which should do the job.

To test it, enter "pacmd load-module module-echo-cancel" in your terminal ; then you should have a new input device with "echo cancelled" in the name.

If you're satisfied, you have to add "load-module module-echo-cancel" to your pulseaudio config file (for me, it's /etc/pulse/default.pa)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have that interference because elementary OS doesn't have noise reduction for the microphone.
Some apps include noise reduction so you can use it on those. You also can reduce a bit the noise by decreasing the volume and/or the gain.
To do so, open a terminal and type `alsamixer`, then press F4 and change the volume and gain levels.
Beware that if you change the microphone volume from any other place it will affect those settings as well.